# Genetic algorithm for matrix in r

Tags: r, optimization

I want to discover the optimal timing of three options m1, m2 and m3

I have to following data for each option(different values for each):

| year | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 23 | 54 | 65 |
| 2023 | 59 | 12 | 3 |
| 2024 | 28 | 65 | 2 |

I want to select the optimal year for each option to maximise the function ( x + y -z) by changing the below matrix.

| year | m1 | m2 | m3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The only limitation is that only one year can be selected for each option.

This will get scaled dramatically. I've tried to use the GA package but there aren't many examples. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. What is your expected output? Do you have an attempt for us to see?

Comment: Is that the actual objective function? Then couldn't you pick the maximum row for *x* and *y*, and the minimum row for *z*?